# Изменение цвета на png программно

Tags: android, android-drawable

Есть изображение .png, это иконка для таба, для нее я сделал селектор, что бы при активном и неактивном табе она имела разный цвет. Пробовал PorterDuff.Mode но результат не совсем такой как я хотел. Меня интересует как можно заменить в селекторе цвет активной иконки динамически. Что бы вместо фиолетовой иконки можно было сделать, красную, зеленую, желтую и т.д.

Пример моего селектора:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- When selected, use icon1 -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_card_e"
    android:state_selected="true" />
<!-- When not selected, use icon2-->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_card_d" />
```

Пример иконки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас одно изображение в котором вы хотите менять цвет в селекторе?

Comment: @DroidAlex в данный момент изображений в селекторе 2 (для активного и неактивного состояния), но несли есть возможность как то изменять цвет хотя бы одной иконки, серой к примеру, то мне и сам селектор в принципе не нужен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Изменить цвет можно так:

**TintIcons.java**

```
public class TintIcons {

    public static Drawable tintIcon(Drawable icon, ColorStateList colorStateList) {
        if(icon!=null) {
            icon = DrawableCompat.wrap(icon).mutate();
            DrawableCompat.setTintList(icon, colorStateList);
            DrawableCompat.setTintMode(icon, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }
        return icon;
    }

    public static void tintImageView(ImageView imageView, int colorStateListResId) {
        ColorStateList list = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(imageView.getContext(), colorStateListResId);
        if (list != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                imageView.setImageTintList(list);
            } else {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(tintIcon(imageView.getDrawable(), list));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**/res/color/icon_state_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@android:color/holo_red_light" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>
</selector>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TintIcons.tintImageView((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_view), R.color.icon_state_list);
    }
}
```

Вместо списка состояний можно передавать просто цвет (например, `R.color.colorPrimary`), тогда картинка просто перекрасится. Аналогично можно перекрасить фон кнопок и т.д. (получив предварительно картинку фона через `imageView.getBackground()`).

Как видно все эти причуды нужны для pre-Lollipop. Для lollipop+ достаточно titnList задать в разметке...

Comment: то что надо, спасибо!