# Как поменять цвет картинки для ImageButton?

Tags: java, android

Есть компонент ImageButton.

Есть набор картинок в формате png, скачаны с [сайта](https://material.io/tools/icons/).

Можно ли поменять программно цвет изображения, с черного на любой другой?

Comment: Заменять картинки не вариат?

Comment: Не вариант. К тому же картинок не одна, а под все разрешения. Зачем плодить мусор. Я где-то видел решение, но не сохранил ссылку, теперь мучаюсь.

Comment: Не понял почему не нашли, очень много подобных тем. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496706

Comment: Да, тем подобных много, но во всех них меняется фон, а не сам рисунок.

Comment: Делал пордобное. Сейчас уже забыл конкретное решение. Помню что использовал что-то со словом Tint. Погуглите запросы с ним.

Comment: ДА!!! Это Tint оказался. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться свойством android:tint

Пример:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tint="#FF0000"
        android:src="@android:drawable/stat_notify_error" />
```